# Calling multiple stored procedure from a main stored procedure in MVC

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a Main stored procedure that calls 4 other stored procedures in it.

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].COMBINED
    @Status varchar(50) 

AS
BEGIN


EXEC StatusMyFamilyProtectionPremier @Status = @status
EXEC StatusMyFamilyProtectionBasic @Status = @Status
EXEC StatusChildeducationSavings @Status = @status
exec StatusChildeducationTerm @Status = @status


END
```

When I executed it in SQL it worked fine and gives me the result set of all 4 inner stored procedures..[image: Stored procedure result]

But when I call the Main stored procedure from my MVC Application I only get the result of the first inner stored procedure.

I am not sure why it doesnt return the result of the other 3 inner stored proceudres.

I called it from my application like this

```
 var life = dc.COMBINED(status);
```

I added the stored procedure to my model directly from the datatbase.

I am not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "I added the stored procedure to my model directly from the datatbase" using Entity Framework, or...? Anyway, the reason for this "issue" is that whatever you're using expects sprocs to return a single resultset, in order to create an entity to put that resultset into. Your sproc is returning multiple resultsets/entities so you will probably have to map those manually... or just call the separate sprocs separately.

Comment: @IanKemp Yeah, I am using entity framework.
I was caling them seperately before, but i decided to find a way to call them at once.
How do I map them manually?

Comment: You can,t cet multi result from entity framework directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the question  here

https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures

Entity Framework by defualt only returns the first result set from a stored procedure,This code allows you to return multiple result sets from a stored procedure in MVC.

If your Stored Procedure has Parameters, then try the code in this link.

https://gist.github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/7310ab2340a7bef43c7307598c8fe101

The code has been modified to return multiple result sets

Comment: Please don't leave the link to the answers, and not the code. To make it easier for future users, please leave the solution to the question in your answer.

Comment: @WynDiesel But the code doesn't belong to me, wont it be wrong for me to write it here??  and the link to the code contains the answers.

Comment: give https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer a read. Links are fine, but it should contain some context.

Comment: @WynDiesel oh okay, I understand what you mean.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your first three table structure the same in above an image. So, you will use the "union" keyword and combined results in a single table and call only a single procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework always return first result set from a stored procedure and doesn't support multiple result sets from stored procedures.

I use [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/) Micro ORM to get multiple result sets from stored procedure.

Comment: I got when i clicked on Dapper.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.